# ADO.NET truncates binary data when passing it to TSQL stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Let me describe the problem:

1. I have a table `T` with a column `C` of type `NVARCHAR(100)`.
2. I have a stored procedure that inserts data into `T`. It has parameter `@c nvarchar(100) NOT NULL`.
3. When I'm calling this stored procedure from my Data Access Layer with string parameter of length > 100, it silently truncates data and no database error occurs. I would like to get 'String or binary data would be truncated SQL Error' instead.

I tried to call stored procedure with clear ADO.NET approach (using `command.Parameters.Add(...)` or `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)`, even tried to specify `SqlParameter.Size = 100`) and with EntLib approach - same result.

If I set bigger parameter size in stored procedure, then it gets passed to stored procedure and a database error occurs. Is setting the stored procedure parameter to `@c nvarchar(MAX)` a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that only ADO.NET is truncating your values? I think that the stored procedure also truncates your values.

To prove it I created a simple stored procedure that has an input parameter `@test nvarchar(10)` and outputs the same value with a `SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure
  @test nvarchar(10)
as
BEGIN
    SELECT @test as result
END
```

If you call this procedure with a parameter longer than 10 the string gets truncated to 10 characters:

**input**

```
testProcedure '0123456789xxx'
```

**output**

```
0123456789
```

So your `INSERT` does not throw any exception because it receives the value already truncated.

Therefore if you want to get an exception from your procedure you have to give the un-truncated value to your `INSERT` statement.

To achieve this you must define your parameter in the stored procedure with a size bigger than the size of the field in your table, for example setting (as you said) `@c nvarchar(MAX)`

Comment: Thank you! I've just realized that I don't need nvarchar(MAX) parameter, I can use nvarchar(COLUMN_SIZE + 1) and this will not allow silent truncation in any cases.